# Rails 5 after_create callback to create has_many :through join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have `Account` and `Page` models that have a `has_many :through` association with my `Campaigns` model.  What I am trying to do is create the join table when I create a new Page using a `create_after` callback.

I also have a `has_many :through` association with `Account` and `User` models.

The current error I am getting is `Account must exist`.  What I am trying to do is grab the `account_id` of the `logged_in` user, but having a tough time.

I included all my models below so you can get the picture of whats happening.  User creates an account, gets activation email, then logs in. 
 At this point, everything created is attached to the account, not the user--in this case I want to create a page and have it create a join table with the account through campaigns.

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :set_membership
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships

  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :pages, through: :campaigns


  # Create Membership
  def set_membership
    user_id = self.owner_id
    Membership.create!(user_id: user_id, account_id: id)
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :accounts, through: :memberships
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts

  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255},
            format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX},
            uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_nil: true
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
  after_create :send_activation_email

  # Non-Admin User Roles
  enum role: [:standard]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, if: :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :standard
  end

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
               BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    # update_columns(activated: FILL_IN, activated_at: FILL_IN)
    update_attribute(:activated, true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest, User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
    # update_columns(reset_digest:  FILL_IN, reset_sent_at: FILL_IN)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  private

  # Converts email to all lower-case.
  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
  end
end
```

**page.rb**

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_campaign
  belongs_to :account

  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :accounts, through: :campaigns

  # Create Campaign
  def set_campaign
    Campaign.create!(account_id: account_id, page_id: id)
  end
end
```

**campaign.rb**

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :page
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails `after_create` callback does not close the transaction in default db strategy. So when you call `after_create` it there is no record in database actually.
Your case you should try:

```
after_commit :set_membership, on: :create
```

Or to provide record instead of id:

```
def set_membership
  Membership.create!(user_id: owner_id, account: self)
end
```